# The Invincible error with Windows Store

Tags: windows-8.1, troubleshooting, windows-store

**PC Configuration**
Asus X53U (Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 dual boot),
problem is seen on- Windows 8.1,
frequency of problem- Everytime the Store is opened

## Long Story, short

Life was running smooth, until one fine morning I found out that I was unable to download any apps from the windows store. I tried all sorts of remedies I could find online (running sfc, dism /restorehealth, dism /componentcleanup, ran the Windows update troubleshooter, wsreset in cmd) but that didn't help. For an insight jump to the screenshots section of this question.

## The Details

'Invincible' would be a word too shallow to describe the problem. After I've tried the aforementioned remedies, and needless to say, every one of them failed, I even did a 'Clean Install' of windows, but still that didn't help. Every time I go to download an app from the windows store, I get a new error. The app search runs fine. The screenshots of the apps also load fine, but despite being on a 4G connection, Store reports me that my Internet connection is 'Too Slow'. Sometimes I get error 0xc03f300d, while sometimes 0x8000405 (refer screenshots for more). And when I go to the 'Your Account' section of the Store, I'm greeted with the problem 'Connection Time Out' everytime. At last I decided to sideload Windows Store apps, so to get a developer License, I opened powershell and opened the Dev-Licensing prompt. The prompt asked me to sign in with my Microsoft account, but after I successfully do so I again get the error 0xc03f300d.

After this I suspect that there may be some problem with the Accounts & sync. My local account is connected to my Microsoft account. A day before all this happened I noticed that windows asked me (about 2-3 times) to sign in with my password as there was some problem. If this is the case please suggest a possible remedy. (That being said, OneDrive loads fine, and other account Sync functionalities work fine, The only problem is with the Store)

I think if things go on this way, my family may feel the need to contact a Lunatic asylum. If possible please help me. All I want is a 'Stable' life and I guess Windows is planning not to give me one.

### Screenshots

[image]

Network Error msg in Store (Notice that I'm already connected to my Home-Network)
[image]

Now this is strange. Two different errors are shown at a time while downloading the same app.
[image]
[image]

**Edit**

Downloaded all recent updates and updated my PC with the most recent updates, still problem persists.

Comment: Apparently you're using a mobile internet access. Is it possible it does not allow HTTPS (SSL) connections?

Comment: @MichaelBay Highly unlikely, unless the ISP was planning to block 60% of websites. Besides, OneDrive works, and that uses SSL.

Comment: @jyotiproy You stated that OneDrive works in your question.

Comment: @MichaelBay, No idea. Https sites do open in browser. If I need to check anything else, please guide me through. Also note I've mentioned that these problems appeared all of a sudden and before that everything was fine.

Comment: One more thing, often I fix the error "Windows update database error" through the troubleshooter. But still the problem persists. If this has anything to do with the store problem, please let me know.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 yup.

Comment: And after installing the latest service stack update (SSU), provided by MS. Update too works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As things stand, the store now works again for me...
Nothing changed on my behalf, so I guess Microsoft fixed something on their side (sync servers?)

Just try again *now*

Comment: Its really surprising. It works now.